# Is there a Keyboard shortcut to open a file and the app to be in full screen mode?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut

I can open an file normally using <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> . But it opens as a normal unmaximized window. How can I open it in fullscreen?

Comment: Try `Cmd + O` then when app opens `Ctrl + Cmd + F`. It'll go full screen if it supports it.

Comment: Try a keyboard configurator.  This allow assigning actions to keys.  Keyboard Maestro is the one that I use.

Comment: @user14492, thanks, I don't know about the `Cmd + 0`, but `Ctrl + Cmd + F` works for me after I open